# Results missing from a mysql FULLTEXT boolean mode search

Tags: mysql, fulltext-index

I'm trying to use a FULLTEXT index in order to facilitate searching for forum posts. It's not working in the way I expect, and I'm trying to understand why not.

For example, I know there is exactly one post which contains the phrase `"haha and i got three"`, so I perform the query

```
select * from forum_posts where
match(message) against ('"haha and i got three"' in boolean mode);
```

and as I expect, I find the single post which includes this phrase. Hooray!

But then I perform the related query:

```
select * from forum_posts where
match(message) against ('"and i got three"' in boolean mode);
```

and get no results. In fact, simply searching for the word "three":

```
select * from forum_posts where
match(message) against ('three' in boolean mode);
```

yields no results either.

What could be going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to learn about stop words and minimum word length.

My default, MySQL ignores stop words in the full text index.  [`Here`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-stopwords.html) is a list of them.  "And I got three" is all stop words.

In addition, by default, MySQL ignores words with less than for characters.  This is controlled by the parameter.  This is explained in more detail [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html).

It sounds like you will want to change the stop word list and change the minimum word length and rebuild the index.

Comment: Ah, yes I expect the stopwords are my stumbling block (and for searching a forum I really shouldn't be using any stopwords I think...). Would the minimum word length play any role in a quoted phrase? (each query's search phrase was longer than 4 characters)

Comment: @Mala . . . In the example in your question, the only word that would be used for searching (by default) is "haha".  All the others are stop words, less than four characters, or both.

Comment: to make sure I understand --  are you saying that it is impossible to search for the exact string "a b c d e f g" without reducing the min word length to 1 character, because each constituent word in the quoted string is only 1 character long?

Comment: @Mala . . . *And* changing the stop word list, because at least "a" is in the default stop word list.